# Export Thunderbird filters to import them in gmail

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, export, import

is there a way to export message filters from Thunderbird and import them to gmail?
I tried the "message filter import/export" add-on but gmail is not able to understand them.

Comment: @dierre- No.  The filtering capabilities of Thunderbird are entirely different then those of `Google Mail`.

Answer (score -3):

Try this addon, I hope It'll help (may not work with thunderbird version 17.0.8)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/thunderbird-message-filter-imp/

Cheers

Comment: It is unsupported for a year, and won't allow import in gmail. -1