# How to import/export filters between accounts in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-filter

I have many fiters and a new mail account. Now I need to transfer them. I already tried the outdated plugin mentioned in [Export Thunderbird filters to import them in gmail](https://superuser.com/questions/600880/export-thunderbird-filters-to-import-them-in-gmail) - but it doesn't work with my up-to-date Thunderbird version anymore.

[image]

Do I need to copy/paste some profile files or is there no way to copy/move filters from one account to another?

Answer (score 3):

Copy `msgfilterrules.dat` from one profile folder to the other, it's that simple!

Comment: Does this also work across version differences and OS differences?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I can't comment (reputation) but anyhow it's case sensitive:

```
$ ~/.thunderbird/jbm20yqp.default$ find . -iname "msgfilterrules*"
...../ImapMail/imap.home/msgFilterRules.dat
```

Uppercase F and R

AFYI. I made it a symlink, so I can use the same rules in multiple accounts (spam is spam wherever it's seen :-) )

It seems my answer was unclear:

1. The original answer of "Copy msgfilterrules.dat..." is basically
   correct
2. It was then questioned WRT "OS differences"
3. On Linux (and I'd guess all OS who honour "case" in filenames, the file is actually called: msgFilterRules.dat  (note the camel-case)
4. The original solution proposed COPYING the file, **which works but** means you need to make future edits in each copy if the rules.
5. Instead I proposed making a symlink (ln -s)  so two or more accounts can share their rules
6. The symlink works, but be aware the file does not appear to be
   read every time it's used (probably only at startup) so edits may not be seen until the next restart
7. I ensure I **make edits to the ORIGINAL** rules (original account) in case the implementation of "edit" recreates the file and so breaks the
   symlink.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK Community Bot, I edited it are you happy now ? Will you remove comment or add another to that effect?